# using parts of Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I know that it is, of course, possible only to use the parts of Boost that you want to use, but my point was, I want to keep my project folder slim. The project should be able to be checked out with all dependencies, and I just noticed while unpacking boost that it is around 33 thousand files and more than 250 megabytes, and I am using one single class of it (tokenizer).

Is it possible only to include a portion of Boost into a project?

Comment: Don't put the files in your project folder, its that simple.

Comment: well, then someone checking out my project wouldnt have all dependencies, and it would be more effort for him to compile it

Comment: If they were already using boost (which they probably are) then it would be less effort as they already have boost in their path. Keep boost in a shared folder and set up your includes so it is found correctly.

Comment: if you make me statically link a library for your project, theres no way I'm compiling it. I want to dynamically link it for efficiency because there a lot of programs using boost.

Comment: alternative: most of Boost is header-only.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) to extract only the subset of boost required by your project.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you would have to look through and copy all of the dependancies from tokenizer as well (recursively).  It is probably going to be a rather big pain.  I also don't know enough about licenses to know if they are ok with you distributing it.